# Returning a string

Tags: objective-c

I have just started with Objective-C and have a (probably) very, very basic question/problem.

```
int testf(int x){
    NSDateFormatter *dateformatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
    NSString *infstr=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[[NSDate] dateByAddingTimeInterval:(60*x)];
    return infstr;
}
NSString *testString=testf(1);
```

I currently have the following problem: I don't know how to return a string from a function. I couldn't even figure it out through Google.

The aforementioned Code leads to a warning "Pointer from integer without a cast". I hope anyone does know a solution to this "problem" and is willing to share it with me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change your return type from int to an NSString pointer like so:

```
NSString* testf(int x){
    NSDateFormatter *dateformatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
    NSString *infstr=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:(60*x)]];
    [dateFormatter release];
    return infstr;
}
NSString *testString=testf(1);
```

*Also your dateFormatter is leaking, so add the release statement as shown above.*

Comment: +1 although his code is a function, not a method (edited answer to reflect that).

Answer (score 5):

You need to create an NSString object using the int.

```
NSString *testf(int x) {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",x];
}

NSString *testString = testf(1);
```

Comment: The OP is not trying to convert an int into a string.

Comment: @mkb It appeared he was in the original question. The original testf function simply returned x.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw yeah, I was pretty confused by your answer and the upvotes when I saw the question. So after posting my answer I looked at the OP's edits. We both provided a correct answer, he just switched the question in the middle. So +1 from me! Ironically, your overall score will be higher than mine for this answer :)

Comment: @theChrisKent Not necessarily. You're only 5 points behind me right now, and since you are marked correct you are more likely to be upvoted by future viewers (+1 from me by the way).